# How to read SMS from a specific port from a sender?

Tags: android, sms, telephonymanager

I am working on an application in which I have read SMS  within application and it should not be stored in phone's default message location.

Sender will send message from a specific port number which has to be handled within app so that it has to be displayed only in the app and not in Inbox.

Kindly help in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your SMS receiver for the specific port:

```
<receiver android:name=".PortBoundSMSReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        <data android:port="port-number-here"/>
        <data android:scheme="sms"/> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

More details [here](http://thamilandroid.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/port-sms-implmentation-in-android/).

Comment: Based on the link which you have provided I have written a program. But now my problem is how to test the application? As incoming message has to come from a specific port number. Can you Pl guide me on this..